# Ubuntu 20.04 Server booting into a GUI

Tags: server, nvidia, upgrade, 20.04

I upgraded my 18.04 Server to 20.04 Server. Did not have GUI on the 18.04 and did not install it on the 20.04. Previously on the 18.04 I had nvidia 310 driver installed and re-installed nvidia 440 drivers in the 20.04 installation. Now it boots into a very limited GUI. I wouldn't mind it if everything was operational in that. Only item that is working is the settings. Nothing else work. No response when I click on any other application icon from the launcher. Also, there is no terminal app. Right now I interact with it over an SSH. Just baffled how the GUI was installed on the machine with this upgrade. Anybody else noticed this?

Comment: I did, I see cloudimages for 20.04 also have GUI by default. How did you deal with that?

Comment: @adamczi I haven't done anything yet. Thinking of installing full blown GUI since the one available by default is very limited. For now I am able to operate it over SSH.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this problem too.

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, it worked for me.

Comment: Really is not the solution, but is a viable workaround, the solution is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250026/ubuntu-20-04-server-suddenly-has-gui-and-no-terminal