# Ubuntu 20.04 Server Suddenly has GUI and No Terminal

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, gui

So I installed Ubuntu server 20.04 just fine, it was running without any GUI just fine.

I've been following [this post](https://illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/26/installing-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-20.html) to install TensorFlow with GPU support and when
I tried to install [NVIDIA Drivers 440](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/440.82/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run) I ran the file and disabled the default Nouveau diver. I believe that everything installed correctly, but after rebooting my machine I seem to be stuck with a GUI that doesn't work. I can open the settings application, but that's it. Nothing else will work/run/start/load etc... I can't even open a terminal window of any kind to try to fix my problem. I don't even have the ability to navigate files using the GUI....

I believe that I have a identical issue to: [Ubuntu 20.04 Server booting into a GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246585/ubuntu-20-04-server-booting-into-a-gui) but no solutions have been offered yet...

I'm fairly new to Linux and have no ideas on how to proceed from here. So any help would be greatly appreciated. I expect I'll just have to reinstall everything, but I don't know how to stop this from happening a second time.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So a quick tip for anyone reading this down the road, but if you install a GUI to your server before updating the graphics drivers, the GUI will be full and responsive. 
This isn't really a viable work-around for me, because I don't want my server to have a GUI at all... but maybe it's an acceptable solution for others. Best of luck and thanks for reading.

Comment: How did you manage to connect via SSH? My workstations seems dead, apart from the limited GUI you mentioned that allows to do nothing interesting.

Comment: To answer you question: I setup SSH before installing a GUI. 
To help with your problem: You want to Disable GUI on startup...
Here's my steps:
1. Install Server
2. Setup SSH, etc..
3. Install Drivers
4. DO NOT REBOOT WHEN PROMTED!!!!!!
5. Disable GUI on startup: >sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target 
6. Reboot

See SHawarden's answer to my other question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250373/server-setup-trouble-i-want-vnc-on-a-headless-server

Comment: Thank you, will try this tomorrow!!

Answer (score 7):

This works up to at least Ubuntu 20.04:
Log in SSH or CTRL-ALT-F3

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution helped me and worked for me for ubuntu 16.04. Able to launch terminal and rest, the terminal is super-duper to do the jobs.

Comment: I confirm it works for `Ubuntu Server 20.04`