# GUI loading on ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, gnome

As title states.

Have ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS installed on my server. It required a system restart.

Upon restarting, it loaded directly into a GUI, which seems to be gnome. Gnome is non-functional (cannot access any applications, i.e. they don't load. Cannot access terminal from GUI).

Would like to revert back to booting straight into command-line, and delete this GUI.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu Server has no GUI packages, so someone will have added packages to your server that caused the change. Rather than suggest *fixes*, I believe it's better to reverse whatever was done on your hardware. You have access to the `apt` logs (/var/log/apt/history.log` so can easily reverse whatever a user with `sudo` rights did to your system (and not risk potential other side effects).

Comment: This site is Question & Answer format..   Can you please write the SOLVED detail in the answer section... then in time you can 'accept' it as your answer & gain some rep. points.  Currently this question has no answers (as your 'answer' is part of the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, @guiverc.

I checked history.log, and uncovered gnumeric, which I installed, also installs gdm3. Have removed both and dependencies. Server working as expected. My experience has been similar to the following questions: [Ubuntu 20.04 Server booting into a GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246585/ubuntu-20-04-server-booting-into-a-gui), [Ubuntu 20.04 Server Suddenly has GUI and No Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250026/ubuntu-20-04-server-suddenly-has-gui-and-no-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Also, if this has happened to others, on log-in screen, Ctrl-Alt-F3 (as suggested by others in above posts) allowed me to load a terminal window, where I could configure and complete the above steps. Hope it helps someone else.